# Magento admin module load different forms with ajax

Tags: ajax, magento

I am developing a module for admin panel.
In module their is master table and 3 child tables. 3 child tabls has 3 different forms.

Records are inserting in master table correctly. now i have added second tab that contains 2 dropdowns, first dropdown has master entries and second dropdown has 3 forms name .  I want to call a form on the basis of second dropdown.

So please help me to call different forms with ajax and i also have to save data of three forms with ajax.

Thanks